# How do I apply different CSS link styles to separate data tables?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

For example; I have one table at the top of my page that is 12 rows wide that I would like to have rounded borders and change colour when I hover over it. My second table (still on the same page) I would like to not have highlights when I hover over a column or row and have a different font.

I know how to apply classes to differentiate tables in my CSS style sheet but I'm not sure how to make it so I can apply these unique properties.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes like (class="table_one") for example and you can use nth:child().